# Secure Browser Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I got a quick question for you guys, I'm new to making Chrome Extensions and the idea I have for one I'm not sure if I can do this with an extension or not. I've been looking through the API but haven't run across something that might help. So my idea for my extension is that whoever downloads the extension will be able to set a pin code they will click the icon and it basically will lock down the browser so if someone else came to the browser they would only be able to access that one page and what it would lead to, they wouldn't be able to us the url bar or have access to the tabs unless permitted.Then the owner can press a hot key and it will ask them for there pin and will unlock the browser if need be.Or even put it in the presentation mode but not able to get out of it without a password? Is this something a chrome extension could do or am I going at this the wrong way? I noticed there are some options in the Chrome://about settings where you can compact the url bar and also make the tabs on the side bar. Any help or direction for this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `options page` where the extension settings are saved, and then create an option called eg **DisableBrowser**.

In file `background.js`, we monitor the `onBeforeRequest` event, and then check the value of variable **DisableBrowser** if it has **true value**, set the value of `cancel` parameter `onBeforeRequest` event, being equal to **true** when `cancel` is equal value to **true**, the request is canceled.

In short, just `cancel` and set equal to **true** and everything is rejected, ie, the browser will not open urls while the extension is installed and enabled.

**Update:**

The sample code below is the content of `background.js` file, showing how to allow only certain urls that are allowed in a list is executed successfully, and consequently all other urls will be denied and fails when opened.

```
// callback
var onBeforeRequestCallback = function( details ) {
  // List of Urls Allowed
  // You can create an array or use localStorage through options.html page,
  // to save the urls allowed,
  // then check and if an allowed URL, the request is not canceled, or in other words, it is permitted,
  // in case of failure it is canceled and is not permitted.
  if ( details.url === 'https://www.google.com/' || details.url === 'http://www.bing.com/' ) {
    return {
      cancel : false
    };
  } else {
    return {
      cancel : true
    };
  }
};

// filter
var onBeforeRequestFilter = {
  urls : [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
};

// opt_extraInfoSpec
var onBeforeRequestInfo = [
  "blocking",
  "requestBody"
];

// Monitors onBeforeRequest event
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener( onBeforeRequestCallback, onBeforeRequestFilter, onBeforeRequestInfo );
```

**Help Links:**

- [options](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options)
- [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)
- [onBeforeRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest)
- [localStorage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

Comment: Cool thanks, so doing it this way can I basically only allow it to use a certain webpage and its/... whatever after it? then block all other sites unless added to the allowed list? Right now i have the extension when press it will make the browser in presentations mode so it will be full screen to kind of take the idea off of the url bar but allowing it if they do scroll up to it and see the url bar if they try to go somewhere it won't let them.

Comment: Yes you can block all URLs except those that are in the allowed list, there are several ways to do this, I think they are really few and if Urls Urls are few, it is not as necessary or use `array` to serve as a list of URLs or `localStorage` you can set all on one line, it gets easier. I'll update the answer of the question with an example code to help serve you added links to help, I believe you get what you need.

Comment: Great thanks for this, I need to do a little more looking at the API and examples to figure out how to implement these different things.